# Will reloading a table cause recompiles downstream?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

We have a vendor that is requesting we truncate a data table, and reload it with the same data daily. The table is 90k rows and approx 10mb. The reason they want this done is so the ETL program picks up that the table has been updated. This table is used in a number of queries.

The question I have is will the changes made to this table cause a ripple effect of recompiles in query plans where this table is used. Or will SQL be smart enough to see that the table contents haven't changed, and avoid the recompiled?

Yes, we know how stupid this is.

Comment: How does the ETL process 'know' the table has been updated or reloaded?  Are there triggers?

Comment: My understanding is the ETL process looks for the table during the load, and if it isn't seen than it assumes the table is stale.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, truncating a table with 90k rows will cause a recompile for any queries that touch it.

You could stop that by turning off [auto update stats](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2766/sql-server-auto-update-and-auto-create-statistics-options/), and in any update-stats jobs or rebuild-index jobs, you exclude this table. However, I'd suggest that you leave it on - after all, the table really could change over time, and you'd want your query plans to update.